# SQL Query - SUM function returning wrong result

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sum, duplicates

I have just started learning SQL and I am doing a school task which goes like this:

"Generate a table of all the continents and the sum of the areas of all those lakes that contain
at least one island for each continent. If a lake is in a country that is situated on several
continents, the appropriate share of the lake area should be counted for each of those
continents."

This is what my database looks like:

https://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Mondial/mondial-ER.pdf (ER-diagram)

https://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Mondial/mondial-RS.pdf (relational schema)

https://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Mondial/mondial-abh.pdf (referential dependencies)

And this what my SQL query looks like (so far):

```
WITH LakesWithIslands AS (
SELECT DISTINCT IslandIn.lake, Lake.area, geo_lake.country
FROM ((IslandIn
INNER JOIN Lake ON IslandIn.lake = Lake.name)
INNER JOIN geo_lake ON IslandIn.lake = geo_lake.lake)
WHERE IslandIn.lake IS NOT NULL
) 

SELECT B.continent, (B.percentage/100)*SUM(A.area)
FROM LakesWithIslands as A
INNER JOIN encompasses as B ON A.country = B.country
GROUP BY B.continent, B.percentage
```

When I run this query I get the wrong sum (it counts the sum of the same lake multiple times) and also get repeated rows of the same continent. I am a complete beginner in SQL (PostgreSQL) and my teacher has not taught us how to do SQL queries before handing us this task (what is she thinking?!) so I am trying to figure this out all by myself and this task to me seems really difficult. Am I overcomplicating this? Is there a easier solution?

I have spent all day trying to do this one task. Is my approach completely wrong? How would you guys solve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You are not using it right. The `SUM` cannot be used like that. You will need to do a subquery to get the `SUM` and then do the multiplication on it. It is an aggregate function and percentage is not aggregated.

Comment: @clinomaniac Even if I remove the B.percentage part in the query I still get the wrong answer because the query sums the area of the same lake multiple times (The same lake and lake area appears in the table multiple times because one lake can be a part of multiple countries/continents). I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Please post [mcve].

Comment: If a lake can be in multiple countries, then your `JOIN`s will duplicate your results. It will help to think of the sets of data you're trying to get, and then make your CTE give you the data for those sets, then use your final query to aggregate that data. Break your query down to show you what you want to see. It'll help.

Comment: Also, don't post links to your schemas. Write out the basics of the schemas in your question. Some of us can't get to the links, besides, clicking on links can bring its own issues. See the above comment about MCVE.

Comment: I think a lake could have more than one island, throwing off your numbers.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In the first inner join statement in my LakesWithIslands table select I already select all of the lakes that have ATLEAST ONE island in them. I am only counting the sum of the areas of the lakes, not the islands so that should not matter... or am I missing something here?